# How to create an anchor link that points to a Joomla K2 Item

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, weblinks

Using Joomla 3.4.1 with the K2 framework.  I want to have an anchor link that points to a K2 item (article). So for example, I want to have a K2 item with several paragraphs of text. Within that text, a phrase would be a link to another K2 item.

It's easy to do this for non-K2 articles by simply using the "create link" feature in the editor. But I haven't seen anything explain how to create a similar anchor link to point to a K2 item.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way or at least the way I achieve the same goal as you have is using [Joomla Content Editor](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/) together with [K2 Links for JCE plugin](http://getk2.org/extend/extensions/869-k2-links-for-jce).

There are also plugins for VirtueMart and other Joomla extensions for this editor. Furthermore, this editor is very customizable in everything you can think of, and is free. Only some of its extensions are paid, but the K2 Links for JCE plugin that you need is free.